# How do I add combobox to my layout? (java)

Tags: java

I wrote this simple layout in java. But It's giving me an error on line 36 & 37 where I implemented the combobox. I don't see why it's not working. It Says

> cannot find symbol symbol  : class
>   ComboBox

Here is the complete code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class DropDownApplet extends Applet implements ActionListener {

   //define variables, Button, label, TextField

      //Create a Button class

   Button btnSubmit = new Button("Submit");
   Button btnClear = new Button("Clear");
    Label lblFname = new Label("First Name");
    Label lblLname = new Label("Last Name");
    Label lblAddress = new Label("Address");
    Label lblCity = new Label("City");
    Label lblState = new Label("State");
    Label lblVehicle = new Label("Select Vehicle Type");
    Label lblHookups = new Label("Select Hookups");
    Label lblArrival = new Label("Arrival Date");
    Label lblNights = new Label("Number of Nights");
    Label lblZip = new Label("Zip");

    TextField txtFname = new TextField(10);
    TextField txtLname = new TextField(10);
    TextField txtAddress = new TextField(10);
    TextField txtCity = new TextField(10);
    TextField txtState = new TextField(10);
    ComboBox cboVehicle = new ComboBox(10);
    ComboBox cboHookUps = new ComboBox(10);
    TextField txtArrival = new TextField(10);
    TextField txtNights = new TextField(10);
    TextField txtZips = new TextField(10);







      public void init() {
      // add the displayable objects;

       setBackground(Color.red);

      add(lblFname);
      add(txtFname);
      txtFname.requestFocus();
      add(lblLname);
      add(txtLname);
      add(lblAddress);
      add(txtAddress);
      add(lblCity);
      add(txtCity);
      add(lblState);
      add(txtState);
      add(lblVehicle);
      add(cboVehicle);
      add(lblHookups);
      add(cboHookups);
      add(lblArrival);
      add(txtArrival);
      add(lblNights);
      add(txtNights);
      add(lblZip);
      add(txtZips);

        add(btnSubmit);
      add(btnClear);

   //Attach event to Button
      btnSubmit.addActionListener(this);
      btnClear.addActionListener(this);

   }

   public void paint(Graphics g) {
      //Draw any pictures
      //Make sure the picture is in the same directory as the .class files


   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   //This method will fire when button is pressed
   //define temporary variables

   }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Java AWT, the [Choice](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Choice.html) Component provides the function you are looking for. If you were making a Swing GUI then you would want to use [JComboBox](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html).

Comment: @Josh, because `Choice` does not have a constructor which accepts in an `int` argument to declare how many columns it supports (like TextField does). For `Choice` only the default constructor `new Choice()` is offered.

Comment: From the javadoc: "Some native platforms do not support arbitrary resizing of Choice components and the behavior of setSize()/getSize() is bound by such limitations. Native GUI Choice components' size are often bound by such attributes as font size and length of items contained within the Choice."

Answer (score 0):

It should be [JComboBox](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html) not ComboBox.

```
JComboBox cboVehicle = new JComboBox();
JComboBox cboHookUps = new JComboBox();
```

And when you are using swing use JTextField, JLable, JButton instead of TextField, Label, Button.

Comment: not if he's consistently on AWT (as it looks, down the override of paint ;)

Comment: @Kleopatra: yes its seems that OP is using awt but he also has imported javax.swing.* so I suggested him if he want to transfer from awt to swing.